# How to "change current line" in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I can "change the word" with `ciw`. I can "change the paragraph" with `cip`.

Can I "change the line" ?

Comment: Well, same number of keys+shift: `^Di` (it's the symbol `^`, not CTRL)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. I figured out `Vc` also, but I was looking for a text object of some kind.

Comment: It looks like there is no text object equivalent for line. `Vc` is even better..

Comment: How about using `S` (equivalent to `cc`)?

Comment: @AlokSinghal Didn't know about that. Closest we'll get. Thanks! Vim help says the following about `S`: `Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start insert.  Synonym for "cc" |linewise|.`

Comment: Yes, and the description for `c` has similar wording, so I think `ciw` and `cc` are equivalent.

Comment: @AlokSinghal Good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim is very flexible by design so you have many ways to "change current line" (and even a few definition of "line"):

```
0C
^C
cc
S
```

and so on…

But you could also create custom "line" text-objects:

```
" excludes linebreak
xnoremap il g_o0
onoremap il :<C-u>normal vil<CR>

" includes linebreak
xnoremap al $o0
onoremap al :<C-u>normal val<CR>
```

that you can use just like `iw` and `aw`:

```
yal    " yank current line, including linebreak   -- like yy
dil    " cut current line, excluding linebreak    -- like 0D
cil    " change current line, excluding linebreak -- like 0C
```

Comment: You forgot `_C` !!

Comment: The list cannot be complete also without `1|C` :)

Comment: It looks like a bunch of weird smilies g_o0